# change the embed's content

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so the idea is i want the bot to send an embed, then take the embed's content, change the footer then send it to **test** channel

this is the code i'm using:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  global test, log, bot_command
  test = bot.get_channel(868816978293452841)
  log = bot.get_channel(858700787815546930)
  bot_command = bot.get_channel(808734570283139162)
  print('bot is ready')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):


  if message.channel == bot_command:
    if message.content:
      await test.send(message.content)

  if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    embed_var = discord.Embed(
      title= '''title''', 
      description= '''description''', 
      color= discord.Color.red()
      )
    embed_var.set_footer(text='old footer')
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed_var)

  # embeds = message.embeds # return list of embeds
  embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict() # the message has only one embed so i'm using this instead of the last line
  for embed in embed_content_in_dict:
    print(embed.to_dict()) # print the content of embed in dict

    # the idea is to take the old embed and post it again with a new footer
    embed_new = discord.Embed(
        title= embed_content_in_dict.title, 
        description= embed_content_in_dict.description, 
        )
    embed_new.set_footer(text='new footer')
    await test.send(embed=embed_new)

  

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

this is the error i get

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 39, in on_message
    print(embed.to_dict()) # print the content of embed in dict
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 37, in on_message
    embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict() # the message has only one embed so i'm using this instead of the last line
IndexError: list index out of range
```

so as you saw, this code is slapped on together and held with the power of dreams and a rookie's forhead.
so my question is how can i make this code work

Comment: You need to assign this `await message.channel.send(embed=embed_var)` to a variable, otherwise you're using the old message.

Answer (score 0):

see this:

```py
...

  # embeds = message.embeds # return list of embeds
  embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict()
  # this is not a dict?
  for embed in embed_content_in_dict: # list(dict) -> dict.keys() -> list[str]
    print(embed.to_dict()) # "str" object has no attribute "to_dict" :)

...
```

be carful. And this:

```py
  embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict()
  # a message can send without embed, so:

  if not len(message.embeds):
    return # break

  embed_content_in_dict = message.embeds[0].to_dict()
```